# Published / unpublished pages

Tags: 2013, publishing

I have a site with published pages (pages library).
I need to know programmatically which page is published and which one is not: if I see the pages library as admin, I see in the list all pages regardless of their status (published, draft etc.), while users can only see the last published ones.
 
The problem is that **as administrator I have not a quick look of which pages are really published**, because in the list I see only the last version (often a draft), but there can be an older published version. To know whether is there a published version or not I need to go into the the Version History.
I could not find in the list a column with the publishing status: **how can I detect quickly if there is a published version or not?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to loop through the Versions and check the status, something like:

```
for (int index = (item.Versions.Count - 1); index >= 0; index--)
{
   if (item.Versions[index].Level == SPFileLevel.Published) 
   {
      // Got the last published item
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to something similar, but I have realized that it can't distinguish unpublished pages: even unpublished pages can have a major version (with int number). I have seen that the system must store in somewhere  else the information about published/unpublished

Comment: For unpublished pages the SPFileLevel will be Draft/Checkout, check [SPFileLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilelevel.aspx).. It doesn't look if its a major version or a minor, it checks what is the Publish status of the page..

Answer (score -1):

You can use this property [SPListItem.HasPublishedVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.haspublishedversion%28v=office.12%29.ASPX)